# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on downloading generated zip

Tags: php, apache, error-handling, zip

So i was trying to generate a zip file with a bunch of pdfs in it.

After some time I got it working but the problem servers gives me ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

- Server's apache is 2.2 on windows server 2003...
- PHP Version is 5.2.

This is the code:

```
<?php
$file_names=$pdfs; //This is an array of names of files in PDF format: 1.pdf, 2pdf, 3pdf...


$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip_name = ("test.zip");
$path_zip = ("C:/www/test/docs/");
$zip->open($path_zip.$zip_name,ZipArchive::CREATE);

foreach ($file_names as $file) {
    $zip->addFile($file,basename($file));
}

$zip->close();

//then send the headers to force download the zip file

header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$zip_name"); 
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0"); 
@readfile($path_zip.$zip_name);
exit;
?>
```

**THE PDFs ARE PREVIOUSLY DOWNLOADED FROM THE INTERNET WITH ANOTHER CODE**

How do I fix this??

EDIT::

Adding a image showing the zip.
[image: Sizes are not real.]

EDIT 2::
I removed the @ at the last line and tested. Nothing works as intended.

Comment: Why is there an `@` before `readfile` still. Stop _suppressing_ errors, while trying to _find_ errors.

Comment: Oops didn't check that... Im testing now..

Comment: That doesn't change anything. Gives same error no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...

It's ugly but it works...

I just changed

```
header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$zip_name"); 
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0"); 
readfile($path_zip.$zip_name);
exit;
```

for

```
header("Location: ".$path_zip.$zip_name);
```

As I say, it's pretty ugly, but it works, it make the user download the file and it doesn't get stuck or something like that.

If someone want to make another true fix, I will test it, as I don't want to change the location.

Bye.